# How to Copy Data From Other Column Based On Other Cloumn Values

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

Here is my datasheet

[image]

I have duplicate values in Column A and Column B. I'm done with getting only unique values from column A in Column C with =UNIQUE(A2:A) formula. But I also want to get only values from B for unique entries I fetch from Column A into Column C. I want to do in Column D but unable to do this. So How I can copy Column B values in Column D against unique values get in Column C via formula. Hope you understand my Question. Sorry for bad English.
For Ex:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like =unique(A2:B) ?

Comment: @JPV Thanks Its Work ... Please make the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @JPV one question please if I want to use this formula only on Column B and Column D and want to skip copy data from column C how we can use this formula? Hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

=unique({B2:B, D2:D})

Answer (score 1):

you can do `UNIQUE` of two columns:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:B)
```

[image: 0]

or you can use `SORTN` with grouping mode `2` like:

```
=SORTN(A2:B, ROWS(A2:A), 2, 1, 1)
```

[image: 0]